# How to Limit Access to a Form using Active Directory?

Tags: permissions, infopath, forms-authentication

I have a specific form that needs to be accessed only by certain users and/or AD groups.  How do I limit access to specified users or specified Active Directory groups?  Is this done via a workflow?

Thanks!!

UPDATE:  It turns out the sections of the form are intended for certain groups.  How do I limit access to certain sections by certain groups?  And, do I need to setup the groups in both AD and Sharepoint, or just AD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the form in it's own document library/form library and set the permissions on the document/form library to the AD group desired.  Alternatively, you can create a single Sharepoint group that contains all the specific users and the AD group and grant that Sharepoint group access to the document/form lbrary.

Comment: When I open this in Sharepoint Designer and attempt to modify permissions, I get an Access Denied error.  Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: It can all be done through the browser UI.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what sort of form it is (list form v. document form), you could also use Audience Targeting to restrict it.